# Optimize the function of searching for an integers which squared summ of dividers will be an integer

Tags: php, loops, optimization

I have this func:

```php
function listSquared($m, $n)
{
    $result = [];
    $integers = range($m, $n);
    foreach($integers as $number){
        $divisors = [];
        $int_of_num = range(1, $number);
        foreach($int_of_num as $number2){
            if ($number % $number2 === 0) {
                $divisors[] = $number2;
            }
        }
        $result[] = $divisors;
    }
    $all_div = array_combine($integers, $result);
    $result_sum = [];
    foreach($all_div as $key => $value){
        $sum = 0;
        foreach($value as $num){
            $sum += $num ** 2;
        }
        $sqrt = sqrt($sum);
        if($sqrt == (int)$sqrt){
            $result_sum[] = [$key, $sum];
        }

    }

    return $result_sum;
}
```

It's working good but taking to much time for an execution. Any ideas how to optimize this code?(Memory of usage)

example of output:

```
listSquared(1, 250)

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 42 [1] => 2500 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 246 [1] => 84100 ) )
```

P.S. This function searching for an integers which squared summ of dividers will be an integer.

Comment: [Thats the wrong forum.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Can you give a example code execution with expected output?

Comment: Please elaborate on the problem statement. It's not clear what you are doing.

Comment: Optimize how? Speed? Memory usage? Readability?

Comment: @Mast I think that i need to optimize memory usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solutuion. If you want to optimize your code, just try to divide your code to functions to get less time of execution.

```php
function listSquared($m, $n)
{
    
    $result = [];
    for ($i = $m; $i <= $n; $i++) {
        $sum = sumDivisorsSq($i);

        if (isSquare($sum)) {
            $result[] = [$i, $sum];
        }
    }
    

    return $result;
}

function isSquare($num){
    $s = sqrt($num);
    return $s == (int)$s;
}

function sumDivisorsSq($number){
    $sum = 0;

    for($i = 1; $i <= round(sqrt($number)); $i++){
        if($number % $i == 0){
            $sum += $i ** 2;
            $j = $number / $i;
            if ($i !== $j) {
                $sum += $j ** 2;
            }
        }
    }

    return $sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could speed up filterings numbers which cant be a divisor instead of trying them out. If a number is odd, the divisor can't be even. Same for squares.
This will reduce your tries by 50%.

Comment: hm... close one. Just need to try.

Comment: Devisor of number can be not onli odd integers... wrong way. And filter just added more time to execution. `$integers = array_filter($integers, function($num){
        return !($num & 1);
    });`

Comment: range ( mixed $start , mixed $end [, number $step = 1 ] ) : array


you dont need to use filter, just dont add it to the range...

step = 2
even start 2
odd start 1